# Only able to search using UNC example: \\server\folder (Windows Server 2019)

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019, terminal-server, file-server

I've had this weird issue where all users that are on a terminal server cannot search when going directly to the directory (example: D:\Shared\Folder shows 0 results). If they visit the same directory using \server\Shared\Folder they are able to search without issues.

Things I've done to troubleshoot:

-Updated server

-Rebuilt index

-Confirmed the whole file drive is included in the index

-Checked extensions in advanced options and saw that all are checked along with "index properties and file contents"

-Added windows search service role.

-SFC / DISM commands

-Reset search options

This is a hyper-v 2019 Windows VM terminal server that users connect to.. There are 2 virtual hard drives (vhdx) total, one for windows, one for file server.

I am out of ideas - I've been trying to find the issue all week.

Comment: welcome, check permissions

Comment: any hugely long file names in there?

Comment: @djdomi permissions are good since they are able to access via UNC.  Tested with my domain admin permission and same issue